# assigning path in Inline javascript in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using MVC 2 architecture.

I have a Javacript file `(x.js)`...which has the declaration for object `hs` (i.e, `var hs`).

In my aspx file I am calling `(x.js)` file using `<script>` tag and it's running properly.

I am using the `hs` variable and assigning values to its properties in my aspx in an inline script - find it below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    hs.graphicsDir = '../../Resources/graphics/';
    ...
    ...
</script>
```

I found this inline script is executing both in my environment and in my publish when i debugged through Firebug.

The problem is, in my environment, the `graphicsDir` value is taken perfect and executing accordingly, but in the publish the path is not taken properly.

Please suggest how to make it run in the deployment also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
hs.graphicsDir ="<%= Url.Content("~/Resources/graphics")%>"
```

Comment: @ganesh .Try using that in js file ..Did not tested yet

Comment: You can't have it in `.js` file as it's not parsed by ASP.NET engine. I will post separate answer, too much to write here.

Answer (score 0):

Following the other correct answer, you can send the correct URL to the client side script using such code in your `Page_Load` method:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "correct_url", "var graphDir = \"" + Url.Content("~/Resources/graphics") + "\";", true);
```

Then in your JS file have this:

```
hs.graphicsDir = graphDir;
```

Since it's MVC application not ordinary ASP.NET you have to follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206153/invoking-a-function-on-page-load-event-in-mvc/2207391#2207391) to add Code Behind - if you prefer to avoid that, you can also have such code directly in the `.aspx` file itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var graphDir = "<%=Url.Content("~/Resources/graphics")%>";
</script>
```

And have the same code in the `.js` file as I explained above. (using the global variable)

Comment: He is using MVC 2.There is no page_load method in  mvc. right?

Comment: No idea, not familiar with MVC but as this question is also tagged ASP.NET there should be something like that *somewhere*. EDIT: see my edit. :)